# IMarker associated with block of text not being removed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, annotations, marker

I created a custom marker and annotation in my plugin.xml using `org.eclipse.core.resources.markers`, `org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes`, and `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification`.

In the code I create the annotation and marker with

```
SimpleMarkerAnnotation annotation = new SimpleMarkerAnnotation( ANNOTATION_ID, marker );
```

Everything seems to work fine. The text has the annotation and the marker appears with the associated area. But when I deleted the block of text that's annotated, the annotation disappears, but the marker is still there on the left side of the editor. Persistent is set to false in the plugin.xml.

The Problems tab in Eclipse doesn't seem to show my inserted markers either.

I created a method to clear out the annotations and markers based on the ID, and that works.

How do I get the marker on the left to also be removed/ disappear when the associated text is deleted?